# List< string > to string[,]

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have a `List<string>` tmpNames that contains names e.g. ("A","B","C","D","E",F").

The size of tmpNames can be different (it is a result obtained from client input).

Now I need to create a matrix with a number of rows and columns.

```
string[,] tmpMatrix = new string[tmpRows.Count,tmpCols.Count];
```

But to iterate and build the matrix I have the following code in which I can not access all items in tmpNames.

```
for(int i= 0; i<tmpRows.Count; i++){
  for(int j= 0; j<tmpRows.Count; j++){
    tmpMatrix[i,j] = tmpNames[i];
  }
}
```

The result that I need is:

> A B C
>   D E F

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to calculate which index you need from `tmpNames` - you need both `i` and `j` for that. You might want to put it on paper to see the pattern:

```
     j=0  j=1  j=2
i=0  0    1    2
i=1  3    4    5
```

Your code should be something like:

```
for(int i= 0; i<tmpRows.Count; i++){
    for(int j= 0; j<tmpCols.Count; j++){
        tmpMatrix[i,j] = tmpNames[i * tmpCols.Count + j];
    }
}
```

Note that I have also corrected the condition in the 2nd loop: you have to compare `j` with `tmpCols.Count`, not `tmpRows.Count`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use separate indexes for Row, Column & source:

```
for(int i = 0, source = 0; i < tmpRows.Count; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < tmpCols.Count; j++){
        tmpMatrix[i, j] = tmpNames[source++];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the indexes in the `tmpMatrix` from the index in the `tmpNames` list and populate it using a single loop:

```
int index = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < tmpNames.Count; index++) {
  tmpMatrix[index / tmpCols.Count, index % tmpCols.Count] = tmpNames[index];
}
```

By using divison and modulo (`%`) you get the result as row and reminder as column:

```
index index / 3 index % 3
----- --------- ---------
  0       0         0
  1       0         1
  2       0         2
  3       1         0
  4       1         1
  5       1         2
```